# Disable SSL certificate pinning

Tags: android, ssl, xamarin

We'd like to have our app, developed with Xamarin Android, undergo a security check. For this reason, we need to disable SSL pinning. What's the simplest way to do this?

We already tried it programmatically, by setting a `ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback` in `HttpClientHandler`, but all we got are lots of exceptions. We also tried that with all combinations of the *HttpClient implementation* and *SSL/TLS implementation* settings in the *Advanced Android Options*, without success.

Our Android Manifest says the following:

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="21" android:targetSdkVersion="23" />
```

If you need more details, please just ask.
Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 0):

SSL Certificate Pinning is introduced in SDK Version 24 (https://developer.android.com/about/versions/nougat/android-7.0.html#default_trusted_ca)

So, there was nothing to do.